# Как сделать автоматическое нажатие кнопки submit?

Tags: javascript, html

Я хочу сделать на сайте автоматическое нажатие кнопки submit через несколько секунд после перехода на страницу , то есть без участия пользователя, что бы передались скрытые данные формы автоматически.

Comment: "Я хочу сделать" - делайте) Что у вас не получилось? Что пробовали?

Comment: Используй ajax вместо формы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так подойдёт?

```js
setTimeout(() => {
   document.getElementById('form').submit();
}, 1000)
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input type="hidden" name="name1" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="name2" value="1">
</form>
```